# Magmi truncating German text

Tags: csv, magmi

I am importing some attributes in German and also exported the file as CSV with UTF-8.
It is truncating some of the German words.

Content of CSV -

header -
sku,affiliate_category_de,type,attribute_set

Text which is getting Truncated -

"Wohnen & Lifestyle > Büro  - Getting truncated to - Wohnen & Lifestyle > B"

"Wohnen & Lifestyle >  Bar & Küche  - Getting truncated to - Wohnen & Lifestyle >  Bar & K"

"Geschenke > Für Kinder  - Getting truncated to - Geschenke > F"

These values are prepoulated in a Global dropdown attribute.

Please advise

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the special characters for Umlaute (ä,ü,ö) and will most likely also happen for 'ß'.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But what's the workaround for it? Waiting for a solution

Comment: The best solution would be to sort out the encoding problem.As I am no magmi expert I cant help you with that. As a workaround you could replace ä with ae (ü>ue;ö>oe) and ß with ss.

Comment: Thanks but I figured it out and solved it with OpenOffice Calc

Answer (score 2):

After searching everywhere came across this forum -

http://understandinge.com/forum/all-things-coding/characters-that-magmi-wont-import/

and used OpenOffice Calc for saving the CSV with UTF 8 and it imported fine without problem.